# Do I really need a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios9.1

I have an existing app (XCode 7.1, Storyboards, Objective-C) that has a UITabController set as the *initial View Controller* , which manages 4 other ViewControllers, one UITableVC, and three UIViewVCs.

I am trying to add a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController; all of the tutorials tell me that I need a UINavigationController.  Since my app is working fine without one for all these years (3+), I don't see why I need it for the search function.

Can someone validate this for me:  do I need a UINavigationController or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 9.1, you should be using UISearchController, not UISearchDisplayController, and no, you don't need a navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks Matt... I've posted another question on how to create the UISearchController since it's not available in IB.  SD

Comment: My book explains it to you, or you can look at the book examples at my github site, starting with this one: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p438searchableTable/ch21p718sections/RootViewController.swift